# Docker multi-stage build with nginx and modsecurity - cannot open shared object

Tags: nginx, debian, mod-security

I have created a docker multi-stage build to be able to end up with a small, lean container with the most recent nginx version and some modules compiled from source.

At the end I copy over the binary and a few other files to the final container - this works fine.

Additionally I'm trying to set up modsecurity as instructed here:
https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-and-installing-modsecurity-for-open-source-nginx/

This also works fine in the original build container. Bu when I copy over ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so to the final target container and launch nginx, it fails with:

```
[emerg] 1#1: dlopen() "/usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so" failed (libmodsecurity.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:10
```

The file definitely exists so the error message is neither very precise nor very helpful.

Since it works in the build container I suspect something else is missing but the error message does not give any helpful clues? What could be missing? Where could I look for further clues? Thanks.

PS: I start from debian:stretch-slim image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By coincidence I found it out now. I had to:

Also copy over:

```
/usr/local/modsecurity
```

and install:

```
libgeoip1 libxml2 liblmdb0 libyajl2
```

Probably because this is a dynamic module.

Answer (score 0):

Try https://hub.docker.com/r/krish512/modsecurity/, it is already built with latest ModSecurity CRS rules

Answer (score 0):

After checking [this issue](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/1603) I got ModSecurity lib properly installed on Debian and globally available by adding this two flags to `./configure`

> --prefix=/usr --with-ld-opt=/usr/lib

---

Prior this, while checking `ldd ngx_http_modsecurity_module.so` I was getting

> libmodsecurity.so.3 => /opt/ModSecurity/src/.libs/libmodsecurity.so.3

which was working fine until I cleaned build files. After removing `/opt/ModSecurity` dir `ldd` was returning

> libmodsecurity.so.3 => not found

and openresty/nginx was failing with the same error message from the question.